# Node Mongodb error : No valid replicaset instance servers found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

We have multiple APIs running on AWS instance on different ports. One of the API is giving error "No valid replicaset instance servers found". Other APIs is working fine. No messages in mongodb log. Tried all other options mentioned in  stackoverflow such as increasing timeout etc. However did not help.

Same API works properly when run on local server. Restarted AWS instance and it started working fine.

Not able to replicate the issue. Any direction to check the root cause. Would like to avoid happening again. Would appreciate any areas to investigate further to find root cause.

Comment: So, it works at localhost, but not with machine address?!?  If so, check firewall that mongo port is open there. You can always check connection using "telnet ip-address 27017" (if your mongo is at port 27017..

Comment: Can you describe your mongodb replicaset, and show us the connection string which your AWS instance is using to connect to it?